# Are there websites for hosting solely academic videos?

Tags: website, audio-video-recording

I have a video from my simulation and would like to add the link to my journal article. However, I do not want to post it on YouTube since I do not want my video next to some random video. Are there websites dedicated solely for this purpose?

Comment: The journal may usually include your videos, animations through hosting links. Ask the editor/contact at the journal.

Comment: @drN Thanks. However, I am looking for something like GitHub where I can share my code.

Comment: I don't understand the argument: "However, I do not want to post it on YouTube since I do not want my video next to some random video". Other videos are not science-related... so what? (BTW: video abstract of New Journal of Physics are on YT: http://www.youtube.com/user/NewJournalofPhysics). (That said, there may be other arguments against YouTube for scientific content - e.g. data preservation.)

Comment: If you post to YouTube you can set the visibility (public/unlisted/private). If you choose unlisted anyone with the link can see it but YouTube will not list it, which seems to be part of your concern.

Answer (score 6):

Usually the journal will host the videos as supplementary material, but if you want to host it externally, there are options. For example, [figshare](http://figshare.com/about) (see also [this blog post](http://figshare.com/blog/A%20YouTube%20%20for%20Scientists/11)).